# VS Code Live Server extension adding/duplicating existing HTML element

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm using the Liver Server extension in VS Code to see the result of some HTML/JS I'm experimenting with, however, it appears Live Server is injecting it's own duplication of one of the HTML elements (in this case an empty div) and joining it onto the bottom of the document. I'm fairly certain Live-Server is the issue here because I've had a look at my code on Codepen and the issue does not appear.

I hope providing a link to Codepen is ok: https://codepen.io/UnmadeBed/pen/PoEoMKy

**main.js:**

```
// grab elements from HTML doc
const body = document.querySelector('body');

// container to hold the grid divs
const containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
containerDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
containerDiv.style.height = '500px';
containerDiv.style.width = '500px';
body.appendChild(containerDiv);

const div = document.createElement('div');
containerDiv.appendChild(div);
```

[image: Chrome dev tools elements tab]
[image: Additional blue div added by Live Server]

Comment: This could be an internal way for the live reload. What's the problem with this empty div?

Comment: It shouldn’t exist. The blue square inside the red container is the only content that should be rendered. I don’t understand how or why Live-Server has rendered a new blue div at the bottom of the red container div.

Comment: I’ve just had a thought. I’ve styled all divs in my css with a single div css selector. I think you’re probably right. It’s likely I’ve inadvertently styled a div that Live Server uses as a live refresh method. I’ll check this out when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It turns out I was accidentally styling a hidden div used by Live Server, as opposed to Live Server duplicating anything.